# What flag has a blue-grey background and an orange-outlined green cross?

Tags: identification, flags

I have a picture of a flag but I do not know where it's from. The cross indicate that it's likely European and it looks very much like the Swedish flag.

Which country has this flag?

[image: Flag has a blue-grey background and an orange-outlined green cross]

Comment: I don't think you're going to get a better answer than "it looks very much like the Swedish flag" especially from this cropped view. The colors look a little off but since it looks like a cheap souvenir flag rather than a professional one that's not surprising.

Comment: @SteveBird except that to be a Swedish flag the colour distortion would have to turn yellow into green while turning deep blue into blueish grey. And introduce orange bands where none such exist.

Comment: I had a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Cross_flag) to no avail.

Comment: Maybe this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Vendsyssel

Comment: @jwenting The flag is black and gold, damnit!

Comment: Are you sure it's a flag and not, for example, the pattern on a jacket or a sleeping bag? Where did you get the picture from?

Comment: Another place to ask would be the flag identificaiton page at  http://www.crwflags.com/fotw/flags/ufe.html

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The pattern you show is called a [Nordic Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Cross_flag). Searching for flags with Nordic crosses comes up with the [Flag of Vendsyssel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_Vendsyssel), which is a traditional district of Denmark and of Jutland. (See [Vendsyssel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendsyssel) at wikipedia)

[image]

> The proposed flag of Vendsyssel in Denmark was introduced by the mayor
>   of Hjørring in 1976, and is used to some extent.
>
> The flag is named Vendelbrog (with reference to the Danish flag
>   Dannebrog interpreted as The Danish cloth).

Note this is a *proposed* flag, and is not officially recognized. As such I don't know that there is an 'official' color set described. The wiki article further states:

> It is a Nordic Cross flag in blue, orange and green. The blue colour
>   symbolizes the sea. The orange/red colour is symbol of the sun and the
>   beaches of Vendsyssel, and the green is for the lush nature. By
>   tradition, only people born in Vendsyssel can use the flag.
>
> The flag is not officially recognised, but it used to be a part of the
>   insignia of the Royal Danish Air Force 723rd Air Squadron.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordic_Cross_flag)

Comment: I think this is quite promising, considering it contains all the same colors, but in a different hue. If the colors are off in that image, or if they are off in the flag itself due to weathering, that could completely explain the difference.

Comment: [Heraldically, colors are not overly precisely defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tincture_(heraldry)), so I wouldn't be too surprised at differences in hue - especially since the Vendelbrog apparently is not officially recognized, so people might have a little more leeway than if they, say, used light blue in the US flag instead of the regulation dark blue.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the flag of the region [Hälsingland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%A4lsingland) in Sweden.

[image]

For some real life examples you can google "hälsingland flagga" (I'm not allowed to post another link).